# Type-alias for enumeration

Tags: matlab, enums, readability, type-alias, magic-numbers

I am working with some code that uses values from an `enumeration` class (extending `uint8`) to access matrix columns "by name" rather than by a hard-coded number. The reason for this approach is that matrices are perceived as more performant compared to other constructs that allow named field access (such as structs/object or tables) - which supposedly improves code readability without sacrificing performance.

The trouble is that the enum class is found inside a package, giving it a rather long name. This hurts readability quite significantly to the point it almost defeats the purpose of "named indices":

```matlab
% What it looks like without using an enum:
val = foo(:, 7); % Magic number, :(

% Current situation (the enum is called "somePackage.SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum"):
val = foo(:, somePackage.SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum.varName1); % Very long name, :(

% Desired solution:
E = somePackage.SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum; % This throws an error in R2020a
val = foo(:, E.varName1); % Short and descriptive!
```

When attempting to use the "desired solution" above, we get the following error:

```
Error using somePackage.SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum
Cannot call the constructor of 'somePackage.SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum' outside of its enumeration block.
```

I have come up with a workaround consisting of storing each enumeration member in a `struct` field with the same name (see [my own answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61587155/3372061)), but I'm wondering if there's a "proper" way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to create a `struct` whose fields are the individual enumeration members:

```matlab
E = enumeration('somePackage.SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum'); % Get all enumeration members
E = [cellstr(E), num2cell(E)].'; % Prepares name-value pairs for `struct` creation
E = struct(E{:});
```

Then `E` is effectively a type-alias for `somePackage.SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum`, and can be accessed as desired.

See also: [`enumeration`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/enumeration.html).

Comment: Interesting approach. Is this actually faster than using a `table`? I know `table` is quite slow, but it's still worth comparing IMO.

Comment: @Cris adding to your comment: TMW published in a [recent blog post](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2020/04/30/faster-indexing-in-tables-datetime-arrays-and-other-data-types/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+mathworks%2Floren+%28Loren+on+the+Art+of+MATLAB%29) that they optimized tables in R2019b-R2020a, so yeah, this definitely should be benchmarked.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative you could consider is to not use an enumeration but a normal class with immutable properties. `somePackage.SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum` would be:

```matlab
classdef SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum
   properties (Constant)
      col1 = 1
      col2 = 2
      col3 = 3
   end
end
```

Then you can do:

```matlab
E = somePackage.SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum;
val = foo(:, E.col1);
```

---

The other approach I was thinking of is using functions (which are traditionally used in MATLAB to define constants), but I can't get that be pretty either. The best approach I found is simply a function that returns the same struct created in the OP's solution:

```matlab
function out = SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum
out = struct('col1',1,'col2',2,'col3',3);
```

Now again you can do:

```matlab
E = somePackage.SomeMeaningfulCollectionEnum;
val = foo(:, E.col1);
```

Comment: I think `Constant=true` is more suitable than `immutable` in this case. Valid solution nonetheless. +1

Comment: @Dev-iL: Right you are!